# How can I handle onclick event of IWURL in delphi intraweb?

Tags: delphi, intraweb

It seems that there is no onclick event handling in IWURL component. Is there any alternative way to perform the task? Or how can I create other forms when the IWURL component is clicked?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found that it can handle asyncClick by using following code

```
procedure Tfrm1.IWAppFormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IWURL1.OnAsyncClick := IWURL1AsyncClick;
end;

procedure Tfrm1.IWURL1AsyncClick(Sender: TObject; EventParams: TStringList);
begin
  //execute code
end;
```